# ffmpeg hangs when running -i in alpine docker container cron job

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, cron, alpine-linux

I'm see strange behaviour in ffmpeg not running the -i option ONLY when running as a cron job. I can run the command fine directly via the shell. The the cronjob command runs, and it even "starts" the ffmpeg "executable", but it then hangs when it gets to the -i option and arguments.

I have included a copy of a working output when run from the shell prompt to demonstrate what the output should show.

alpine: 3.13.5

docker image : alpine:latest (date: 2021-05-14)

docker run :

`docker run -v s:\_docker\_alpine-test:/media/pi --name alpine -it alpine crond -f -l8`

crontab script :

`/media/pi/_site/pics-alpine.sh 2>&1 | tee /media/pi/_site/alpine.log`

/media/pi/_site/pics-alpine.sh script :

```
#!/bin/ash

set -xv

echo "START"

#encode jpgs to mp4
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg  /media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4

echo "END"
```

The output of the log file is :

```
echo "START"
+ echo START
START

### encode jpgs to mp4
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg  /media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4
+ /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '/media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg' /media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (Alpine 10.2.1_git20210328) 20210328
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --enable-vulkan --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwebp --enable-libaom --disable-debug
```

Script output when run directly from the shell prompt :

```
/media/pi/_site # ./pics-alpine.sh

echo "START"
+ echo START
START

### encode jpgs to mp4
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg  /media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4
+ /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '/media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg' /media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (Alpine 10.2.1_git20210328) 20210328
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --enable-vulkan --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwebp --enable-libaom --disable-debug
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, image2, from '/media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x960, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] profile High, level 3.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] 264 - core 161 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1280x960, q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   24 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      25kB time=00:00:00.84 bitrate= 242.1kbits/s speed=1.56x
video:24kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.565835%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.30  size:  3693
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] frame P:11    Avg QP:20.46  size:   854
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] frame B:11    Avg QP:22.05  size:   623
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] consecutive B-frames: 29.2% 25.0% 12.5% 33.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] mb I  I16..4: 14.6% 83.5%  2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] mb P  I16..4:  3.0%  2.2%  0.0%  P16..4:  5.2%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:89.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  6.5%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:92.9%  L0:35.0% L1:64.8% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] 8x8 transform intra:73.3% inter:94.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 8.5% 12.1% 0.5% inter: 0.7% 3.3% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 77% 15%  6%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 71%  6% 20%  1%  1%  0%  1%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 55% 13% 24%  1%  3%  1%  1%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 92%  4%  4%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] ref P L0: 57.6%  2.5% 30.8%  9.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] ref B L0: 70.2% 27.6%  2.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] ref B L1: 98.5%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd9cf099b00] kb/s:196.96

echo "END"
+ echo END
END
```

As you can see from the above, when run from the shell prompt it starts ffmpeg and then processes the arguments. But when running as cron, it opens ffmpeg, but ignores, or hangs on the processing of the arguments.

Lastly, I have the following show up in ps ax when I do a check to see what is running:

```
   58 root      0:00 /bin/ash -c /media/pi/_site/pics-alpine.sh 2>&1 | tee /media/pi/_site/alpine.log
   59 root      0:00 {pics-alpine.sh} /bin/ash /media/pi/_site/pics-alpine.sh
   60 root      0:00 tee /media/pi/_site/alpine.log
   61 root      0:00 /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /media/pi/to-video-back/%04d.jpg /media/pi/_site/back/back-latest.mp4
```

Those are just sitting there as though they are waiting on input, so I suspect the ffmpeg has a bug, or my cron is not passing the arguments correctly.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: You probably need to add the `-y` global option to the FFmpeg command to overwrite the output file without asking.

Comment: nope, no difference, output is the same, no file produced either. It is literally as though ffmpeg the executable is launched, but does not see the -i input argument. I suspect this could be a bug, but it is a very weird one as I've never seen this behaviour before.